# Convert DateTime to MySQL TimeStamp

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime, timestamp

I am doing this to save a `DateTime` in the MySQL database but when stored, the value is `2011-10-30 06:01:07`. `06` is supposed to be `pm`, not `am`:

```
startTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with existing .NET providers for MySQL, but you you might want to investigate if you could put your date into a parameter instead. That may both have security and performance benefits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply do this

```
startTime.ToString ("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

where `HH` (capital H) shows 24 hours format. So when you try saving `2011-10-30 06:01:07` it suppose to be `am` and when you want `pm` you should save `2011-10-30 18:01:07`

Answer (score 1):

Add the value using `parameters`:

```
MySqlCOmmand cmd=new MySqlCommand(
    "INSERT INTO MyTable(myDate) VALUES(?myDate)", connection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?myDate", startTime);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```