# SSRS: Parameter not filtering MySQL query

Tags: mysql, reporting-services, parameters, mariadb

I have a Date/Time parameter to my report:

[image]

But when I run my query, I get no results:

```
 SELECT HD_QUEUE.NAME as qname, HD_TICKET.ID, HD_TICKET.CREATED, HD_TICKET.TIME_CLOSED, CUSTOMER.FULL_NAME as custfullname, 
     HD_STATUS.NAME as statname, HD_TICKET.TITLE, left(ASSIGNEE.FULL_NAME, 40) as assignee, 
     HD_PRIORITY.NAME as pname, HD_CATEGORY.NAME as catname
    FROM  HD_TICKET 
     INNER JOIN HD_QUEUE
    ON HD_TICKET.HD_QUEUE_ID = HD_QUEUE.ID
    INNER JOIN USER CUSTOMER
    ON HD_TICKET.SUBMITTER_ID=CUSTOMER.ID
    INNER JOIN USER ASSIGNEE
    ON HD_TICKET.OWNER_ID=ASSIGNEE.ID 
     INNER JOIN HD_STATUS 
     ON (HD_TICKET.HD_STATUS_ID=HD_STATUS.ID) 
     AND (HD_TICKET.HD_QUEUE_ID=HD_STATUS.HD_QUEUE_ID)
    INNER JOIN HD_PRIORITY
    ON HD_TICKET.HD_PRIORITY_ID = HD_PRIORITY.ID
      and HD_TICKET.HD_QUEUE_ID = HD_PRIORITY.HD_QUEUE_ID
      INNER JOIN HD_CATEGORY
    ON HD_TICKET.HD_CATEGORY_ID = HD_CATEGORY.ID
    and HD_TICKET.HD_QUEUE_ID = HD_CATEGORY.HD_QUEUE_ID
    left join ASSET on ASSET.ID = HD_TICKET.ASSET_ID
    left join ASSET_DATA_6 on ASSET.ASSET_DATA_ID = ASSET_DATA_6.ID
    WHERE (HD_STATUS.NAME = 'Closed'
    AND HD_TICKET.TIME_CLOSED < @date_param);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: TIME_CLOSED, what is it, a TIME, DATE or DATETIME?

Comment: TIMESTAMP in mysql

Comment: Looks like a conversion issue. Does this answer help -->https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7944317/convert-datetime-to-mysql-timestamp

Comment: I had thought that it might be a data type issue, but it looks like datetime and timestamp store in the same format. And conversions I've tried don't seem to work.

Comment: FROM_UNIXTIME(@date_param) and 
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(@date_param) didn't work

Comment: Can you place a label on the report and set the expression to =Parameters!date_param.Value and post what value is displayed.

Comment: I get back: 3/30/2018 12:00:00 AM

Comment: There are many answers on here on how to convert to a timestamp from various formats. I don't have MySQL so I cant test, however, I bet you need to convert from one format to the required format for comparison.

Comment: Actually it's a MariaDB. I've also tried DATE_FORMAT(@date_param, '%Y %m %d') and variants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL does not allow named parameters. Use '?' instead of '@date_param' in the query.

```
WHERE (HD_STATUS.NAME = 'Closed'
AND HD_TICKET.TIME_CLOSED < ?;
```

Then check the Dataset Properties and make sure the '?' is associated with the value of your parameter:

[image: Parameter Name field is ? and Parameter Value field is the name of your parameter]